# Is it possible to set an object's location as the default location during an animation?

Tags: animation, mesh

I'm trying to put balls into a shape that resembles a grape. The Youtube tutorial I followed ->>>>> (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHawJobP_fI&t=68s)

The image below is the way I put the balls in the shape of the grape, I changed the settings so that the balls are affected by gravity and once I start playing the animation they fall into the "container".

[image]

My question is that is it possible to set the position of the balls as default during some point of the animation?

Here is how I give the balls their shape ↓↓↓

[image]

Comment: why don't you just keyframe the location when you are satisfied? then you can move the keyframe to frame 1 - if you want

Comment: Good Idea! Thanks for your help Chris :)

Comment: You are welcome